# User with admin role can have many hotels, but how can an admin invite a user for just one of its hotels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

**Context**
I cannot grab my head around the following:

- There is a many-to-many relationship between User and Hotel via a join table User_Hotel.
- A User created with devise has an admin role
- A User with admin role can create many Hotels
- A User with admin role should be able invite other Users to a specific Hotel (e.g. not all of its Hotels). I am using the devise-invitable gem to sent the invitations.

**Issues**
I set up my routes, models and controller for users/invitations, but something is wrong:

1. as my hotel_id params are not sent properly to my invitations_controller. See error message:
   `Couldn't find Hotel without an ID. params sent: {"format"=>"109"}`
2. I am not sure if/how I should create the connections between this specific hotel en user that is invited?

**views/hotels/show**

```
<%= link_to "invite new user", new_user_invitation_path(@hotel) %>
```

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    invitations: 'users/invitations'
  }

  resources :hotels do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

**models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :hotels, through: :user_hotels
  enum role: [:owner, :admin, :employee]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :admin
  end

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :invitable
end

class UserHotel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :user
end

class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_hotels

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: ->(attrs) { attrs['email'].blank? || attrs['role'].blank?}
end
```

**controllers/users/invitations**

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @user = User.new
    How to build the join table UserHotel when inviting?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

IDK if the user that is invited to a hotel needs accept or not.

**If needs accept:**

You need a table to store Invitations where you will store `user a` invite to `user b` to a `hotel a`. Then you need `inviter_id`, `invited_id`, `hotel_id`. When user accepts the invitation you will add a record to your intermediate table relating hotel and user.

Another way is in your intermediate table add a flag to control which are accepted and which no yet and add a default scope over relation to get only the accepted.

**If user will directly added to the hotel:**

You only need do:

```
@hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
@user = User.new
@user.hotels << @hotel
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate feedback. I'm using the devise-invitable gem, so I believe the gem does this for me. I'm already using the ```@hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])```, but I get the error message ```Couldn't find Hotel without an ID. params sent: {"format"=>"109"} ```